# How to write model function in yii html view file

Tags: php, class, view, yii, model

I'm working on **yii old version** i need to write model function in view file this file is html format i don't know how to call model function.  I need to send this value  `{{ $model->customers_charge->shop_id }}` to model function

My code is :

```
{{foreach $models model}}
              <tr>
                <td>{{date('M/d/Y H:i', strtotime($model.created))}}</td>
                <td>{{if $model->deposit>0}}{{$model->deposit}}{{/if}}</td>
                <td>{{if $model->deposit<0}}{{$model->deposit*-1}}{{/if}}</td>

                <td>
                {{if $model->memo eq Order}}
                Shopping Order 
                {{else}}
                {{$model->memo|ucwords}}                
                {{/if}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              {{/foreach}}
```

How to get model function in Yii framework.can any one kindly guide me. I'm looking forward your valuable reply.

Comment: where is your <?php tag ???

Comment: and what is `{{/if}}` ???

Comment: Hi Alireza Fallah, we can write above like that coding in view file without php tag

Comment: is that some kind of template engine markup?

Comment: @suresh, okay, I didn't know it :0

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this ?

```
YourModelName::model()->YourFunction($arg1,$arg2);
```

Or

```
$model = new YourModelName();
$model->YourFunction($arg1,$arg2);
```

Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Hi @Alireza Fallah, it does not support template file (.html) it works only .php file.

Comment: so why dont you use .php file instead of template?

Comment: because so many functions are build in html file format like pagination and payment process. i cant change it